# How to restore changed properties of a data binded object?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm stuck and I hope for suggestions. I'm talking about only in-memory objects. No databases or files involved here.

Basically I have an object whose properties I've bound to some text- and combo-boxes. When I change the value in a texbox, the value in the bound property gets also changed, obviously. What I want to achieve is, that when I change the value in a texbox, the change should be made only temporarily.

This is what I do:
I load my data and then the main form gets opened with a list of all my data items. I double click an item and another form gets opened where I bind the properties of the item to some textboxes. I change something and click cancel. Now if I open again the same item, the changes are still there.

I want the changes to be temporarily so only if I click save, then the item should be updated. I can't figure it out, how to do it with a data bound object. **I guess I miss the point of Databinding?**

I could make it easy by assigning the values of my item properties to the textboxes and write the values in the texboxes back to the item properties as I click save. But isn't Databinding made for this kind of work or am I completely off?

Should I query my database again to restore the original data of that specific Item, if I want to use Databinding?

Edit: As suggested in the comments, I can use a copy of the item and save its changes to the original item, as I click save. But what is a good way to enforce that the form is working with copies of that item only? The view should not need to know whether its a copy or not or that it should make a copy first.

Comment: You can't modify the object you're using to data-binding. If your 'temporary' changes are modifying your object, then, you need to repopulate it again. If you're not modifying it, then, just do a databind again.

Comment: Create a temporary object and modify that. On save copy all changes to main object.